# Deleting and purging Rasa-x from Ubuntu after installing it with the one line bash script

Tags: python, ubuntu, rasa, rasa-x

I installed Rasa-x with the one line script.

this is the script mentioned in the doccs (https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/one-line-deploy-script)

```sh
curl -s get-rasa-x.rasa.com | sudo bash
```

I can see that my localhost path is listened on Rasa-x which i dont know what service did that.
And i dont have much knowledge with kubernetes and bash to read the script.

please help me to purge all the side effects.
if you can tell me what process is live on my machine, it would be so nice.

Comment: consider asking Ubuntu-related questions on https://askubuntu.com/
Also, can you please be a bit more specific? I don't understand most parts of your question.

Comment: There is not going to be a short answer here. Read through the script and figure out how to reverse each thing it did.

Answer (score 4):

there should be an uninstall script provided by the installed embedded K3s cluster. Running `/usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh` should remove the cluster.

May I ask which problems you where running into?
We are currently working hard to improve the script. Adding an uninstall option will definitely be a part of it.